# Group by X and count the NULLS in the same col

Tags: mysql

Here is my query:

```sql
SELECT 
    CONCAT( YEAR( prm.fromdt ) , '|', MONTH( prm.fromdt ) ) AS k, 
    CONCAT( YEAR( prm.fromdt ) , ' - ', MONTH( prm.fromdt ) ) AS v,
FROM prm
GROUP BY k
ORDER BY `k` DESC
```

Which returns:

```
K       V
2009|7  2009 - 7
2009|6  2009 - 6
NULL    NULL
```

Is there a way Instead `NULL NULL` to get how many nulls I have? Something like

```
K       V
2009|7  2009 - 7
2009|6  2009 - 6
Nulls   6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
SELECT CONCAT( YEAR( prm.fromdt ) , '|', MONTH( prm.fromdt ) ) AS k, 
       coalesce(CONCAT( YEAR( prm.fromdt ) , ' - ', MONTH( prm.fromdt ) ), cast(count(*) as varchar(255)) AS v   
FROM prm
GROUP BY k
ORDER BY `k` DESC
```

I don't like mixing data of different types in one column.  However, this might meet your needs.

Comment: After everybody is against mixing types I will try to avoid that. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Add a `COUNT()`

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT( YEAR( prm.fromdt ) , '|', MONTH( prm.fromdt ) ) AS k, 
    CONCAT( YEAR( prm.fromdt ) , ' - ', MONTH( prm.fromdt ) ) AS v,
    COUNT(*) AS c
FROM prm
GROUP BY k
ORDER BY `k` DESC
```

Which should return

```
k              v             c
2009|7  2009 - 7    {count of this group}
2009|6  2009 - 6    {count of this group}
NULL    NULL         6
```

Comment: the idea is to don't add new col

Comment: @Martin Why not? A new col is better than mess count value with other values.

Comment: I will follow your advice, I will separate the count value. 10x all.

Answer (score 1):

Building on the answer from xdazz:

```
select k, case when v is null then c else v end as v
from
(
SELECT 
    CONCAT( YEAR( prm.fromdt ) , '|', MONTH( prm.fromdt ) ) AS k, 
    CONCAT( YEAR( prm.fromdt ) , ' - ', MONTH( prm.fromdt ) ) AS v,
    COUNT(*) AS c
FROM prm
GROUP BY k
) x
ORDER BY `k` DESC
```

but as dazz points out, you're then mixing column types. You could easily cast the count to a string value, but that doesn't get around the fact the consumer is implicitly getting mixed data types in column `v`.

Answer (score 0):

The basic SQL is:

```
COUNT(somefield) WHERE prm.fromdt IS NULL
```

But how to actually use this depends on what exactly you are doing. It sounds like what you want is not the same as what you are doing with the dates. If you mix the two, it is likely to be messy.

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to do this in one query without adding new columns because i have a heavy php behind dealing with 2d array